# Issue returning updated variable from function in C

Tags: c

Hi I'm trying to learn how to go about using functions in C so I'm doing a basic calculator activity but having an issue with the processing_input function. Heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char receiving_input(char *input)
{
    printf("Enter input: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    return *input;
}

char processing_input(char *input, int number)
{
    if (*input == '-') {
        number--;
        printf("%d\n", number);
        return number;
    }

    if (*input == '+') {
        number++;
        printf("%d\n", number);
        return number;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int number = 0;
    char input[15] = "";

    while (1) {
        receiving_input(input);
        processing_input(input, number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The receiving_input function works perfectly, as it returns the input of user perfectly to main function. However the processing_input function does not return the updated number variable to the main function as I wish. Example output of code:

```
Enter input: +
1
Enter input: +
1
Enter input: +
1
Enter input: -
-1
Enter input: -
-1
```

This seems to be because *return number;* isn't returning the updated number which has either been subtracted or increased by 1. I want the output to actually be like this:

```
Enter input: +
1
Enter input: +
2
Enter input: +
3
Enter input: -
2
Enter input: -
1
```

Can't seem to find the right fix. Help is much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correctly returning a value from the function, but you aren't doing anything with the return value.  You need to assign it back to `number`:

```
number = processing_input(input, number);
```

Also, the return type of `processing_input` should be changed to `int` to match the type of the value you're returning.  You also don't need to return anything from `receiving_input`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Have implemented all of your suggestions with no issue.